# Present ModalView over PopoverView in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad

I am trying to develop an application which needs to present a view modally while loading the app from background. Now my issue is that if there is any popover opened before sending the app to background then the modal view will be presented behind the popover. I used `viewcontroller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;` method to solve the issue. This one solved my issue but this is causing another issue like if I rotate the device while showing the presented view and dismiss that, then the actual view  behind that appears to be  distorted, all locations frames seems to be changed.

Please share your thoughts about the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is dismissing any active pop over just before your app goes to background not an option for you?

Comment: But how can I present the same popover again at the same position,because a lot of popovers are there in my app.So i need to hanlde this in a general way